# Is there a way to keep the same header and footer thoughout a document that has multiple section breaks on the same page of a word doc?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to keep the same header and footer thoughout a document that has multiple section breaks on the same page of a word doc? When I use the Same as Previous option for the header and footer, it does not go back to section 1 to get the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. First check that "Different First Page" is not checked. If this is not the case I think the problem is with continuous sections "Same as Previous" setting. If the document is not big you can (make a backup first) remove continuous sections, then make sure "Same as Previous" is set for every section, then reinsert continuous sections.

If that doesn't work (and for big documents) the following macro works for me in such cases (tested in Word 2010):

```
Sub LinkToPrevious()
Dim s As Section
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sections
    With s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        .LinkToPrevious = True
    End With
    With s.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        .LinkToPrevious = True
    End With
Next s
End Sub
```